# Cannot increase save_size beyond 79999

Tags: pdftex

I have two identical ThinkPad laptops, an old one under Windows 7 with 8Gb RAM and a new one under Windows 10 with 16Gb RAM. I am transitioning between the old one and the new one. I am using the same MikTex 2.9 distribution on both. I use WinEdt as editor on both.

All my LaTeX projects compile (pdflatex) nicely on the old laptop.

All my LaTeX projects compile nicely on the new laptop EXCEPT the largest one which is indeed very large: 80 files, 3600 pages output PDF, multiple index, lots of cross references, use of minitoc, ...

The execution error is:

```
!TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save_size=79999]
```

I upgraded the new laptop's memory from 8 to 16Gb, added the line

```
save_size=159999
```

to `pdflatex.ini` and recompiled (build format) with the MikTex console. I then get an error in the `pdflatex.log` file:

```
Bad Parameter Value.
Info: parameterName="save_size"
```

Anyone has an idea? Thanks for looking anyway.

Comment: I don't know miktex's limit. Older texlives used 80000, currently it seems to be 100000 but I just checked three and a half thousand log files I have lying around and none used  5 digit save stack other than test files that are testing save stack usage, are you sure your document is not in error and using more save stack than needed?

Comment: Thank you David. Could you tell me exactly what save stacks are and what creates them ? What puzzles me is the fact that the project compiles on the old laptop with Win7 and does not under Win10.

Comment: save stacks is where tex stores things to restore so `\def\zz{a}...{ \def\zz{b} ... } here \zz is a again`   the values that need to be restored at the end of a group come from the save stack. This is built in to tex and highly unlikely to be operating system specific. If you can access the machine where it works look at the final line of the log that tells you how much stack you used, and how big the stack is. a typical log line is `51i,1n,73p,821b,317s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,1000s`  in a document where I used at most 317 entries out of 1000 in the save stack.

Comment: Thank you David. This is puzzling. On the Win7 laptop, the end of the compilation shows:

Comment: Thank you David. This is puzzling. On the Win7 laptop, the end of the log file shows:

46i,19n,49p,6784b,1545s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

which is well below the limit. The SAME project (the files are on OneDrive so that I am sure that I am indeed compiling the same project) on the new laptop shows the number of save_stacks exploding. 

So you were right, something must be looping and unduly creating over 80.000 save_stacks. But I have no idea where to look for differences between my two installations.

Comment: look at the two log files, and compare package versions, somewhere you will be inputting different code

Comment: Indeed the Miktex 2.9 build is not the same and most packages I use do not have the same time stamp. Compiling a single chapter is successful on both laptops but the number of save_stacks is not the same. Adding more chapters leads to a moderate increase of save_stacks on my Win7 installation and  to a faster growth on Win10. Eventually the count exceeds 80000 on Win10 and stays below 2000 on Win7. The problem is that I cannot (or maybe I can ?) find the older package versions to install them on Win10 ... and I don't want to take the risk of upgrading my Win7 installation.

Comment: start with a _copy_ of your document and delete stuff that you can delete while showing the problem, once it is small enough to post here add a complete example  here and someone will debug, otherwise it is very hard for anyone to answer, sorry. It sounds like one package you are using has a bug that is making it eat the save stack in its new version, but impossible to debug that with the information you have posted so  far.

Comment: Got it. I will do that. Thanks for helping me so far. I really appreciate.

Comment: The problem is related to the paracol package. A readme.txt and all required data files of a MWE are downloadable as a compressed archive from https://www.dropbox.com/s/nn1l97typofy2d5/MWA_JLM.zip?dl=0. I'd be infinitely thankful if anyone could help. Already great thanks to David Carlisle who helped me understand my problem better.